# How we can allow multiple domains with xframe-options for IE 11 browser?

Tags: spring, spring-security, internet-explorer-11, x-frame-options

I have one **URL https://xyz.mydomain.com/app1/** and app1 is based on spring framework, I want to access this webapp from:

- xyz1.mydomain.com,
- xyz2.mydomanin.com

and also in future this can be accessible from:

*.mydomain.com
I have tried with CSP but its working on from Chrome and Firefox only and it's not working on IE 11.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail that what do you mean by not working? Did you got any error or warning message or you are getting different output? from your description, it looks like a routing related issue. How and where did you configure it? If possible than try to provide steps to produce the issue without using any third party apps. than we can try to test the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 doesn't understand CSP. X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM is only designed for a single domain.

Basically your options would be:

- Don't care about adding security for the tiny fraction of users still using an outdated browser lacking modern security standards. Just implement CSP and drop X-Frame-Options.
- Test hacks to X-Frame-Options such as adding the header multiple times or insert multiple domains all with a trailing slash.
- Set X-Frame-Options in code based on a whitelist of acceptable domains.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have implemented with "Test hacks to X-Frame-Options such as adding the header multiple times or insert multiple domains all with a trailing slash." Its works for all browser